# Take out number in range arc4random ( )%x

Tags: ios, int, arc4random

I am using arc4random to generate a random number. I generate a number between 0 and 2. This is an identifier for a color-change in the game loop. If the number is equal to 1 the following generation
should exclude the number 1.
How can I do this?

```
int x = arc4random()%3;
```

Comment: So you want to randomly get either a 0 or a 2? If this is the case why not do arc4random()%2 and if the result is 1 add 1 to it? Also it's generally better to use `arc4random_uniform` to generate random numbers between 0 and a bound as this will generate the numbers uniformly whereas doing a `%` won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two primary ways to do this.

The simpler but potentially less efficient:

```
int x;
do {
    x = arc4random() % 3;
} while (x == 1);
```

or slightly more complex but more deterministic:

```
int x = arc4random() % 2;
if (x > 0) x++;
```

Comment: Don't do it the first way with a number generator that is actually random it is never guaranteed to come out of the do while loop.

Comment: yeah, i took the second way, thats so simple i'm ashamed i didn't get on that by myself :D

Answer (score 1):

Exclude it:

```
uint32_t identifier = 1; // << the number to exclude
uint32_t NIdentifiers = 1;
uint32_t NNumbers = 3;
uint32_t NPossibleIdentifiers = NNumbers - NIdentifiers;

uint32_t result = arc4random_uniform(NPossibleIdentifiers);
if (identifier == result)
 ++result;
```

---

Note: favor `arc4random_uniform` over `arc4random` and modulo.